# How to create array this data

Tags: php, arrays

Please help me.

I want to create an array like this.

```
{
    "polyline": [
        [-5.40044378489256, 105.256219301373],
        [-5.40040246210992, 105.255722338334],
        [-5.40040673688054, 105.255641704425],
        [-5.40068350732327, 105.254918346182],
        [-5.40083421394229, 105.254701003432]
    ]
}
```

how implement in php `array()`?

Comment: Actually that is an object, not an array - at least in terms of JSON. // What is your actual, specific problem with creating this? Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you tried, and explain where exactly the problem lies.

Comment: change `{` with `[` and `:` with `=>`

Comment: `$arr = [[-5.40044378489256,105.256219301373],[-5.40040246210992,105.255722338334],[-5.40040673688054,105.255641704425],[-5.40068350732327,105.254918346182],[-5.40083421394229,105.254701003432]]`?

Comment: just use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php); with associative parameter as true

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid JSON actually. You can convert it to PHP array by using `json_decode()`, like:

```
<?php
$data = '{
    "polyline": [
        [-5.40044378489256, 105.256219301373],
        [-5.40040246210992, 105.255722338334],
        [-5.40040673688054, 105.255641704425],
        [-5.40068350732327, 105.254918346182],
        [-5.40083421394229, 105.254701003432]
    ]
}';

$arr = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [polyline] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => -5.4004437848926
                    [1] => 105.25621930137
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => -5.4004024621099
                    [1] => 105.25572233833
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => -5.4004067368805
                    [1] => 105.25564170443
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => -5.4006835073233
                    [1] => 105.25491834618
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => -5.4008342139423
                    [1] => 105.25470100343
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx Guys ,

solved with this method .

```
$datapolyline = array('polyline' => $items);
$encode = json_encode($datapolyline);
$hasil = str_replace(']"',']',str_replace('"[',"[",$encode));
```